# Etymology of "age of majority?"

Tags: etymology

What is the etymology of the phrase "age of majority," meaning, e.g., 18 in the US? Does it have something to do with democracy, the age at which one can vote, and the fact that democracy is based on the will of the majority? Or does it come from some other, unrelated sense of "major" or "majority?"

Comment: Have you researched any of this? A good start is etymology.com. What did you learn? What question remains, exactly?

Comment: @CanisLupus Did you mean [etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the relevant definition of *majority*. Here is what *Black's Law Dictionary*, revised fourth edition (1968) has to say about that term:

> **MAJORITY.** Full age; the age at at which, by law, a person is entitled to the management of his own affairs and to the enjoyment of civic rights. The opposite of minority.Also the *status* of a person who is a major in age.

That definition notwithstanding, under law a person need not necessarily have reached a certain fixed calendar age in order to become a "major." Here is the relevant part of Black's definition of that term:

> **MAJOR.** A minor emancipated by marriage. [Case citation omitted.] A person of full age; one who is no longer a minor; one who has attained the management of his own concerns and the enjoyment of his civic rights.

Every now and then we hear about child stars who have gone to court and obtained a judicial order granting them at least some aspects of majority (particularly with regard to control of their wealth), despite their youth. And of course, as the surprising oxymoron "emancipation by marriage" indicates that, when a minor marries an adult (following the appropriate approvals required as safeguards), he or she gains majority in many, though not all, respects.

The notion of emancipation from pre-adult constraints is crucial to the legal sense of *majority* because in legal Latin, just as in bear-constellation-name Latin, *major* means "greater." Thus (Black's explains) in Old English law, the term *majores* referred to "Greater persons; persons of higher condition or estate"; and in law of indeterminate age, the term *majora regalia* referred to "The king's dignity, power, and royal prerogative, as opposed to his revenue, which is comprised in the *minora* regalia."

So *majority* in a legal sense carries the idea of the enlargement of one's freedom and power to the full size possessed by any free adult citizen. Since *majority* itself comprehends the notion of "full age," the phrase "age of majority" seems a bit redundant;, and it is hardly surprising that Black's doesn't include definition for that phrase. Legally, "reached majority" says everything that "reached the age of majority" says, and does it in three fewer words. (This may come as a bit of a shock to people who assume that one element of the practice of law consists in saying things in as many words as possible.)